# Static vs. Instance Write Methods in Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer

I am creating a Data Access Layer in C# for an SQL Server database table.  The data access layer contains a property for each column in the table, as well as methods to read and write the data from the database.  It seems to make sense to have the read methods be instance based.  The question I have is regarding handling the database generated primary key property getter/setter and the write method.  As far as I know I have three options...

Option 1:  Using a static method while only allowing a getter on the primary key would allow me to enforce writing all of the correct values into the database, but is unwieldy as a developer.

Option 2:  Using and instance based write method would be more maintainable, but I am not sure how I would handle the get/set on the primary key and it I would probably have to implement some kind of validation of the instance prior to writing to the database.

Option 3:  Something else, but I am wary of LINQ and drag/drop stuff, they have burned me before.

Is there a standard practice here?  Maybe I just need a link to a solid tutorial?

Comment: A couple of frameworks I've used, will update the primary key automatically when you save the record, based on what the database gives. This let me avoid bothering with the primary key at all. I could also set it, but then potentially run into an issue of the database rejecting me setting the primary key. You could also keep the property as a standard property, but in your save() or update() methods, make sure to ignore updating the primary key column - which would be weird as a developer, i'd rather see an error like (you tried to set a primary key and the db rejected you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to read up on [active record patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) and some examples of them, and then implement your own class/classes.

Here's a rough sketch of a simple class that contains some basic concepts (below).

Following this approach you can expand on the pattern to meet your needs. You might be OK with retrieving a record from the DB as an object, altering its values, then updating the record (Option2). Or if that is too much overhead, using a static method that directly updates the record in the database (Option1). For an insert, the database (SP/query) should validate the natural/unique key on the table if you need to, and probably return a specific value/code indicating a unique constraint error). For updates, the same check would need to be performed if allowing natural key fields to be updated.

A lot of this depends on what functionality your application will allow for the specific table.

I tend to prefer retrieving an object from the DB then altering values and saving, over static methods. For me, it's easier to use from calling code and can handle arcane business logic inside the class easier.

```
public class MyEntityClass
{
    private int _isNew;
    private int _isDirty;
    private int _pkValue;
    private string _colValue;

    public MyEntityClass()
    {
        _isNew = true;
    }

    public int PKValue
    {
        get {return _pkValue;}
    }

    public string ColValue
    {
        get {return _colValue;}

        set
        {
            if (value != _colValue)
            {
                _colValue = value;
                _isDirty = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Load(int pkValue)
    {
        _pkValue = pkValue;

        //TODO: query database and set member vars based on results (_colVal)

        // if data found
        _isNew = false;
        _isDirty = false;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        if (_isNew)
        {
            //TODO: insert record into DB
            //TODO: return DB generated PK ID value from SP/query, and set to _pkValue
        }
        else if (_isDirty)
        {
            //TODO: update record in DB
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx). I know you said you are wary of LINQ, but EF4 takes care of a lot of the things you mentioned and is a fairly standard practice for DALs.

Comment: I am a control freak.  I consider this drag/drop functionality and a leaky abstraction.  I can't have the EF writing some crazy query underneath.  Thanks though.

Comment: @Ben Entity Framework was made by the same people that made c# and SQLServer - they're designed to work together. EF is very solid, and as a generalization I'd probably find a bug a lot sooner in a DAL I wrote myself than in EF.

Comment: Performance is paramount. Entity Framework uses two layers of object mapping and the additional mapping has performance costs making even simple queries about 16x slower than a data reader.  Plus I consider it drag/drop functionality so it does not answer my question.

Comment: @Ben Are you sure you're not prematurely optimizing? Performance is important, but rolling your own ORM, even on a small scale, is probably going to take you a hell of a lot longer than using an ORM like EF or nHibernate. And will the performance be worse with an ORM? You really don't know until you try it and profile it. I've used nHibernate for several applications and rarely had issues with how it performed or the queries it generated. And when it generated a query that I wanted to hand-tweak, it was easy enough to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with an ORM Tool (EF, OpenAccess by Telerik, etc) unless you need a customized dal that you need (not want) total control over.  For side projects I use an ORM - at work however we have our own custom DAL with provider abstractions and with custom mappings between objects and the database.

Answer (score 0):

Nhibernate is also a very solid tried and true ORM with a large community backing it.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is the way to go for your initial DAL, then optimize where you need it: Our company actually did some benchmarking in comparing EF vs SQL reader, and found that for querying the database for one or two tables worth of information, the speed is about 6's (neither being appreciably faster than the other).  After two tables there is a performance hit, but its not terribly significant.  The one place that writing your own SQL statements became worthwhile was in batch commit operations.  At which point EF allows you to directly write the SQL queries.  So save your self some time and use EF for the basic heavy lifting, and then use its direct connection for the more complicated operations.  (Its the best of both worlds)